# Product custom taxonomy terms loop - image has empty src

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to get the ACF image field which is set to URL to show in my query. This is being shown in the shortcode `[short_minerals]`. The field name is `mineral_image`. The taxonomy name is `minerals`. The hyperlink is showing properly, and the code is showing all taxonomy terms successfully. Yet, the image URL appears as `<img src=" ">.` I've tried changing the ACF image field name and changing the output. This is a custom product taxonomy, and the shortcode is shown on the single product template.
The code is as follows:

```
function minerals() {
$terms = get_the_terms( $product_id, 'minerals' );
foreach ($terms as $term) {
$product_term = $term->name;
$term_slug = $term->slug;

//get the term id to get the acf field from
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id;
$term_image = get_field('mineral_image', $term_id);

//output the template
?>
<div>
    <img src=" <?php $term_image ?>" />
    <?php echo "<a href='/minerals/" . $term_slug . "'>" . $product_term . "</a>"  ; ?>
</div>
<?php
}

}

// register shortcode
add_shortcode('short-minerals', 'minerals');
```

I'd really appreciate any help here! Thanks.

Comment: You need to put the appropriate prefix before the term id, otherwise `get_field` will try to find meta data on a _post_ object with that id. https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: get_queried_object() returns id of current page. $term_id = $term->term_id should do ?

Comment: Tried using $term_id = $term->term_id; .The src returns empty still!

Comment: CBroe what do you mean by prefix? What's the code part that needs to be changed after implementing Martin's code ?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, the variable was not passed to the img tag. I wrote `<img src="<?php the_field('mineral_image', $term); ?>" />` and that worked.